# iframe submit get the posted content

Tags: javascript, post, iframe

Using an iframe to post a submit, it has a file upload. everything is working fine up til the returned content.

If i show the iframe on the page, i see the html that was returned from the function in my iframe. Having much trouble getting the content of the iframe to replace the content of the page.

Basically get the content of the body iframe and place it in the body tags of the page.
I'm sure its 1 or 2 lines, but every jquery or document or getElementById idea i've found on the web is not working.

I do notice something odd, if i try to use "console.info('somemessage')" in my reload function, it throws an error saying console does not exist. Not sure why, but seems my javascript focus is in the iframe and can't see firebug.

Heres the code stripped down. Back to trying the .load event, which is working. but its that second line that trys tot write the content to the body. when i comment it out, the iframe shows, with my content. If i run it uncommented, the whole page reloads.

```
        if (isStarted == false) {
            isStarted = true;
            statustracker.start();
            //style="height:0px;width:0px;"
            var iframe = $('<iframe name="postframe" id="postframe"  class="hidden" />');
            $('div#iframe').append(iframe);

            $('#ImportDetailForm').attr("target", "postframe")
            form.submit();

            $("#postframe").load(function () {
                iframeContents = $("iframe")[0].contentDocument.body.innerHTML;
                $("body").html(iframeContents); // <--- the problem
            });
        }
```

Comment: All the form settings(attr) are in the form tags. The form object is an object in jquery validate submithandler.

Answer (score 0):

In your parent page (the one containing the iframe), you could set an event listener for the 'message' event, like so:

```
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
function receiveMessage(e) { ... }
```

Then in your iframe, just post a message to the 'parent' window like this:

```
parent.postMessage(someString, parentUrl);
```

Because messages are strings, you'll need to serialize any data you're sending between iframe and parent window - I suggest JSON!  So in your case, serialize the returning HTML from the upload request and post it to the parent, then deserialize it on that side and inject it into the DOM.

Comment: I can't figure out how to get the iframe contents serialized. trying to use jquerys/json .serialize() but is not working.

Answer (score 0):

An invalid or illegal string was specified" code: "12

probably because iframeContents is empty.

```
            $("#postframe").load(function () {
                var win = document.getElementById("postframe").contentWindow;
                var parent_url = decodeURIComponent(document.location.hash.replace(/^#/, '')), link;
                iframeContents = $("#postframe").find("body").contents().serialize(); //$("iframe")[0].contentDocument.body.innerHTML;
                console.info(iframeContents);
                //$(this).parent("body").html(iframeContents);
                win.postMessage(iframeContents, parent_url, parent);
            });
```